# Modify existing Authorization module (email to username)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to modify the existing Authorization module provided by Laravel 5, instead of asking for the `email` it will ask for the `username` field in the database.

Answer (score 35):

Laravel search the variable $username in the file :

> Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers

```
public function loginUsername() {
    return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

As you can see, by default it will be named as 'email'.

However you can override it in your AuthController by adding :

```
protected $username = 'username';
```

Comment: Sir, I've been looking for this answer all afternoon. How did you know that you can set the $username property? Thanks, by the way. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hi. What is $username and what is 'username'? I have in my DB col called "name", which I would like to use for authentificate. Should I use 
protected $username = 'name'; ? Because it doesn't work for me :( Laravel 5.3

Comment: Working now... You also need to update view->login.blade.php You need to change input name from email to username

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to modify the Auth module to do this, simply pass the user's identifier in the attempt. Use the field name in the attempt array as such:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]))
    {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: Yep, I did that, what I worry is also how can I always check the user session, just like how the default Auth module does it?
`public function __construct() { $this->middleware('auth'); }`

Comment: The identifier used does not affect the function of the Auth module in any way.

Comment: sorry but I can't find the "attempt array" or the pattern "Auth::attempt(" anywhere in my project. Can somebody just tell where to change what to get it work? thanks!!

Comment: how to login using both username and password?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to check the file `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` just to get the idea.

Then add an override of `postLogin` on your `AuthController`:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'username' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
                ]);
}
```

You also need to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to your `AuthController`.

Comment: You'll need also to update `app/Services/Registrar.php` for registration. It requires email and puts in database.
Also with easy auth you'll need to update `views/auth` form names.
I think that's it.

Answer (score 5):

you can just override auth username function from LoginController.php in laravel 5.3

```
public function username(){ 
   return 'username';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in  controllers\auth\logincontroller add this

```
 protected $username = 'user_name';//user_name field name
```

then go to Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers and change

```
 public function username()
    {
         return 'email';//change this with "return $this->username;"
    }
```

with this method You can have different log in type in different controller for example in another controller controllers\admin_auth\logincontroller

```
protected $username = 'phone_number';
```