# Log in Using Email and Username by Changing in AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. I need to log in my users either with username or email. I am changing the following piece of code from the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php file:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{


    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);



    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
                ]);
}
```

with the following code.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{


    $field = filter_var($request->input('loginfield'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';


    $this->validate($request, [
        'loginfield' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);



    if ($this->auth->attempt([$field=> $request->only('loginfield'), 'password'=>$request->only('password')], $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('loginfield', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
                ]);
}
```

I also changed the code from login.blade.php accordingly. But when I pass credentials to it. It throws error "Email field is required."  In login.blade.php, I made two changes. 1. changed the input type from "email" to "text" and 2. name from "email" to "loginfield". Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The LoginRequest class is perhaps running to validate the controller. Have a look at `App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest`

Comment: Thanks Ben, I checked App\Http\Requests.. There is no LoginRequest.

Comment: Apologies, LoginRequest was part of the heavier Auth framework and doesn't exist in tagged 5.0, it was in there during the development process.

Comment: I think Guard.php needs some sort of modifications...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Modify existing Auth module (email to username)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584531/laravel-5-modify-existing-auth-module-email-to-username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding postLogin method in the AuthController is the solution instead of changing vendor directory if we want to implement our own requirements.