# In Laravel 5, how make sure a user is authed uniquely?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm searching for a solution to allow a user to be logged in only once at the same time. I'm new to Laravel and in this case I'm using it nearly out of the box (file session driver and default auth-handling with custom views).

My idea is to 'reset' the auth for a user after he logs in a second time, to automatically make all other active sessions invalid.

So my primary question is: Is there a way to accomplish this with some Laravel magic or do I need to invent this feature myself?

Comment: I think this post answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425311/laravel-5-1-how-to-limit-account-access-so-one-account-can-be-accessed-at-one-t/31447737#31447737

Comment: This is a nice approch (and similar to the ones underneath), but to me this solution seems not reliable enough, as IP and/or device information can be spoofed or just be the same.

Comment: The device hash as I proposed could be anything you like. You could, to be extra sure, create a unique device hash based on various parameters combined with a unique identifier you generate. To make this even more un-spoofable you could you some JS device fingerprinting tool that fetches all sorts of parameters (https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs) for example.

Comment: Okay, convinced. ;) Thank you! A side note: You liked the deprecated version of the GitHub project. This is the new one: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the new version of the project. I'm getting old. Feels like yesterday the version I pointed out was brand new.

Answer (score 0):

What you also could do is the following:

In your usertable, add one column:

```
sessionID (varchar or text)
```

Now what you want to do here is the following: 
When a user logs in, store the ID of the session in the sessionID field. Everytime the user loads a page, or makes a request, check if the sessionID value in the DB is the same as the sessionID of the user that is logged in. If it isn't, kill the session and make him login again.

Now, when a user logs in, check the usertable if the sessionID value is already filled. If so, change it to the new sessionID. The result will be that all requests with the old sessionID will be invalid (because of your check) and the user can only access your webapp/website with the new session.

Thus this makes sure that your user is authed uniquely.