# Laravel Auth/Guard not signing in using valid credentials

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

This is a follow-up on my previous question regarding form requests, which has now been resolved. Unfortunately, the app will not sign in with the correct credentials. I've had this issue before, and the solution had something to do with the session - however, this is not the case here as the session is being set correctly, as well as a key.

When providing the correct credentials, `$auth->attempt()` returns false.

**Schema:**

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $t) {
    $t->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $t->timestamps();
    $t->rememberToken();
    $t->boolean('system')->default(false);
    $t->boolean('activated')->default(true);

    $t->string('username')->unique();
    $t->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
    $t->string('passphrase', 64);
    $t->string('first_name', 20)->nullable();
    $t->string('last_name', 20)->nullable();

    $t->text('meta')->nullable();
});
```

**Seed:**

```php
$adminUser = App\User::create([
    'system' => true,
    'username' => 'SysAdmin',
    'passphrase' => bcrypt('the-password'),
]);
$adminUser->attachRole($administratorRole);
```

**User Model:**

```php
namespace App;

use Bican\Roles\Contracts\HasRoleAndPermission as HasRoleAndPermissionContract;
use Bican\Roles\Traits\HasRoleAndPermission;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, HasRoleAndPermissionContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, HasRoleAndPermission;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['system', 'username', 'email', 'passphrase', 'first_name', 'last_name'];
    protected $hidden = ['passphrase', 'remember_token'];
}
```

**AuthController::attemptSignIn() method:**

The user may sign in with either their username or email address.

```php
public function attemptSignIn(SignInRequest $request = null, $type = 'regular')
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'regular':
            $identifierFieldName = 'account_identifier';
            $field = filter_var($this->request->input($identifierFieldName), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
            $this->request->merge([$field => $this->request->input($identifierFieldName)]);
            $specifics = $this->request->only($field, 'passphrase');
            if ($this->auth->attempt($specifics)) {
                return redirect($this->redirectPath);
            } else {
                return redirect($this->signInPath)
                    ->with('authError', "The credentials you've provided are incorrect.")
                    ->with('authErrorType', 'danger')
                    ->withInput($this->request->only($identifierFieldName));
            }
            break;

        case 'oota':

            break;
    }
}
```

The information set in `$specifics` is correct, and matches the record in the database.

Perhaps I am missing something simple?

Comment: I have a feeling that Guard is looking for `password` and not `passphrase`. Will a simple override fix that?

Comment: Hmm, giving this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073309/how-to-change-custom-password-field-name-for-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-user-auth

Comment: Ah, that worked. `password` is hardcoded (pity). Just switch they key out when authenticating so that I need not change field names here. Passphrases are not passwords, and policy for this app is to **not** use passwords, but rather longer passphrases that are easier to remember, and harder to break.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584531/laravel-5-modify-existing-auth-module-email-to-username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584531/laravel-5-modify-existing-auth-module-email-to-username)

Comment: Yes, you can do that for usernames, but not for passwords. It uses `password` internally for hashing on `attempt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26073310), `password` is hardcoded into Laravel's authentication protocol. As such, I simply needed to change the array sent to `attempt`:

```
$specifics['password'] = $specifics['passphrase'];
unset($specifics['passphrase']);
```