# Laravel 5.1: How to login using both username or email fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

There is an option available to login using the **username** or **email** fields at a time. But I would to login to site using both fields, username OR email,
means: if user input value is matched with username column or email column, then login to the system.

laravel 5.1 having trait **AuthenticatesUsers** contains this code. which only checks for single column.

$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
}
```

Kindly guide me, login attempt for both column (email or username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to validate the form field, just have username validation as well in your validation rules

Then in your controller validate the login like

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])){
//suceess
}
elseif (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
//logged in using email
}
else{
echo fail
}
```

Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584531/laravel-5-modify-existing-auth-module-email-to-username) as well