# Laravel: simplest/right way to save a new step after login?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm having my first interaction with the core laravel code so I want to be careful not to break anything.

In my project, my users also correspond to person records (via user->person_id), so I have a get_person_from_user() function that takes the \Auth::user() (conveniently accessible anywhere) and returns the person object, so I can grab the person record for the authenticated user from any controller and pass it to a view.

The problem: there's a piece of data from the person record that I'd like to include in a nav partial in my default blade view (which gets extended by a bunch of different views), so it's the one case where I'm not going through a controller first. I'm unclear on how I can make the logged in user's person record available here. Any suggestions?

I think I need to add some step after the user logs in, to save the person record (globally? in the session?) so it's generally accessible.  The login stuff happens in AuthenticatesUsers.php, and [reading around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584531/modify-existing-authorization-module-email-to-username) it sounds like I'll want to add an override of postLogin to my AuthController. 
But I tried copying that function from AuthenticatesUsers.php into my AuthController (not adding anything else to it yet), and AuthController gives me a new error when I try to log in:

```
ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist
```

Any advice on a good way to go about accessing the person object for the authenticated user, when I don't have a controller to pass it along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the correct relationship on the User model to Person model.

```
public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Auth::user()->person;
```

For having a variable available to a particular view you can use a View Composer. (You can create and register a Service Provider and add this to the `register` method.) Potentially something like this:

```
view()->composer('someview', function ($view) {
    if ($user = Auth::user()) {
        $somevar = $user->person->somevar;
    } else {
        $somevar = null; // or some default
    }
    $view->with('somevar', $somevar);
});
```

If this view is also used in a scenario where someone doesn't have to be authed you will want to check if `Auth::user()` is null before trying to use the relationship.

[Laravel Docs - Views - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Eloquent [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)

**User.php**

```
public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('NAMESPACE_TO_YOUR_MODEL\Person');  //also you can specify FK, more info in docs
}
```

then you can access `Auth` facade in your view

```
Auth::user()->person
```