# php artisan auth Username / Email

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how to modify AuthenticatesUser.php in Laravel 5.3 so that I can login using Username or Email. I have also username field in my users table. I cannot find the query. Or if there is other way using Laravel 5.3 auth.

Comment: Assuming you already have a way to differentiate whether the user has entered an email or username, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31387345/4121010) seems to be the best way to override `AuthenticateUsers`. It works by setting the `$username` property of your `AuthController` to the name of your _username_ column.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I solved it by now. Manipulated the attemp method its either username or email.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 - 5.2 you would add

`protected $username;`

To your `AuthController`

In Laravel 5.3, you can add this to the `LoginController`:

```
/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: "use protected $username" is this not a syntax error?

Comment: Yes it is, can't believe myself haha. `protected $username;` would be right.