# laravel 5.3 built in login/auth querying for wrong field name

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am currently trying to implement the Laravel 5.3 login/auth, and have updated my User model fields and location to match my database. However, I cannot seem to find where Laravel is querying my table for field name 'email'. I edited the Validator::make function in RegisterController to stop trying for unique:users with 'email', yet it persists. Here's my error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tblUserAccount` where `email` = email@email.com limit 1)
```

It has the correct table, but the field on that table is sEmail, not email. This field is on my User model. Where can I change this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584531/modify-existing-authorization-module-email-to-username

Comment: Off-topic though, I would advise against naming your column like that.

Comment: @Mihailo Do you mean the table?

Comment: Well now that you mention it @ceejayoz both.

Comment: @Mihailo Oh! I missed that OP changed it to `sEmail`. Yeah, that's weird. Laravel standard would be `users` table with `email` column.

Comment: @Mihailo not my fault, eventually I'll get this DB to make sense but for now it is what it is

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses `email` field by default for authentication.

In 5.3 you can try to override [`username()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L139) method in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` like this:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'custom_username';
}
```

Also, you'll need to change rules in `validator()` method in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`.

Comment: override this where? on the User model?

Comment: In `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`