# auth::attemp not working properly laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My login in laravel isnt working properly. I've been stuck here for a long time now. This is my login controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class UsersController extends Controller
{
protected function dashboard(Request $request)
{

    if (Auth::attempt(array('account_number'=>$request['accountnumber-login'], 'password'=> $request['txt-password']))) {
        return redirect()->intended('viewdashboard');
    }

} 

protected function viewdashboard()
{
    return view('dashboard');
}
}
```

..in this controller the 'account-number' is the account number column in the database and the 'password' is the password column in the database. I've done everything correctly yet it does not redirect me to the dashboard view. Please help

and this is my html form

```
<html>
<form action="dashboard" method="GET">
<input type="number" name="accountnumber">
<input type="password" name="password">
</form

</html>
```

this is my web route folder

```
Route::get('dashboard', function(){
return view('dashboard_view');
}
```

pls help, please.

Comment: do you have cedentials stored in users table ?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: it just doesnt show me the view i want even though the inputs are correct. It ust shows me a blank page with the dashboard route

Comment: @Niklesh ive dont that and now it says an error which says: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from users where 0 = 2110729927 limit 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the UsersController in the route.

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@dashboard');
```

Also you are accessing request data the wrong way.

Use

```
$request->input('accountnumber');
```

EDIT:

And thirdly the dashboard method must be public

```
 public function dashboard(Request $request)
```

Comment: but is the array correct??, or do you have another programmer good practice

Comment: the problem is that its not redirecting. Can i redirect to my controller

Comment: its not redirecting well

Answer (score 0):

You're getting values with other names that you put in your form, try this to get the values in your controller:

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{ 

if (Auth::attempt(array('account_number'=>$request->input('accountnumber'), 'password'=> $request->input('password')]))) {
    return redirect()->intended('viewdashboard');
}
```

NOTE: the method must be public

additionally you have to either add other route to get the dashboard request or rename the route which you're pointing your form.

```
Route::get('auth', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@auth');
```

update your HTML form as well.

Comment: ive dont that and now it says an error which says:   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `0` = 2110729927 limit 1)

Comment: the username is a email or ID? if you're using the default authenticate should be email, so update the attemp with this:`if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>$request->input('accountnumber'), 'password'=> $request->input('password')])))` @OGPaulCaleb

Comment: if you want to change the email by other field, take a look of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584531/modify-existing-authorization-module-email-to-username